# How to improve the performance of my NServiceBus Saga under load

Tags: nservicebus, saga, nservicebus-sagas, nservicebus7

I have a very simple Saga built with NSB7 using SQL Transport and NHibernate persistence.

The Saga listens on a queue and for each message received runs through 4 handlers. These are called in a sequential order, with 2 handlers run in parallel and the last handler only runs once both the parallel handlers are complete. The last handler writes a record to DB

Let's say for a single message, each handler takes 1 second. When a new message is received, which starts the Saga, the expected result is that 3-4 seconds later the record is written to the DB.

If the queue backs up with say 1000 messages, once they begin processing again, it takes almost 2000 seconds before a new record is created in the last handler. Basically, instead of running through the expected 4 second processing time for each message, they effectively bunch up in the initial handlers until the queue is emptied and then does that again for the next handler and on and on.

Any ideas on how I could improve the performance of this system when under load so that a constant stream of processed messages come out the end rather than the bunching of messages and long delay before a single new record comes out the other side?

Thanks
Will

Comment: Have a look at the ServicePulse Monitoring and try to find what is causing the delay, you may find that you have a lot of retries due to concurrency exceptions?
If this is the case you might want to revisit your design.

Comment: Yeah, have checked ServcePulse which shows no retries, only confirms that All 1000 messages complete the first Handler before moving onto the second handler.

Comment: May be best to open a case with support suport@particular.net, https://particular.net/support

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation for saga concurrency issues: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/concurrency#high-load-scenarios

I still don't fully understand the issue though. Every message that instantiates a saga, should create a record in the database after the message was processed. Not after 1000 messages. How else is NServiceBus going to guarantee consistency?

Next to that, you probably should not have the single message be processed by 4 handlers. If it really needs to work like this, use publish/subscribe and create different endpoints. The saga should be done with processing as soon as possible, especially under high load scenarios.